# Serving caffe models from GPU - Achieving parallelism

Tags: caffe

I am looking for options to serve parallel predictions using caffe model from GPU. Since GPU comes with limited memory, what are the options available to achieve parallelism by loading the net only once?

I have successfully wrapped my segmentation net with tornado wsgi + flask. But at the end of the day, this is most equivalent serving from a single process. https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/web_demo/app.py.

Is having my own copy of net for each process a strict requirement, since the net is read-only after the training is done? Is it possible to rely on fork for parallelism?

I am working on a sample app which serves result from segmentation model. It utilizes copy on write and loads the net in the master once and serve memory references for the forked children. I am having trouble starting this setup in a web server setting. I get a memory error when I try to initialize the model. The web server I am using here is uwsgi.

Have anyone achieved parallelism by loading the net only once (since GPU memory is limited) and achieved parallelism for serving layer? I would be grateful if any one of you can point me in the right direction.